# Why is this style using pseudo-class first-child selector applied to all elements in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have this User component where I just want the first child to have a top border:

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import styles from "./User.module.css";

const User = (props) => {

  return (
    <tr className={styles.user} onClick={(e) => {
      e.target.classList.toggle(styles[`toggle-${props.color}`])}}>
      <td className={styles["user-row"]}>
        <div>{props.user}</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  );
};

export default User;
```

This is it's css module:

```
.user {
    text-transform: capitalize;
    padding: 0.5rem 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.user-row{
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: solid 2px black;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 2.5rem;
    padding-left: 1rem;
}
.user-row:first-child {
    border-top: solid 2px black;
}
.toggle-blue {
    background-image: var(--blue);
    color: #fff;
}
```

But it renders a top border for all rows not just the first one.

Comment: Your all `td` elements has a bottom-border as far as I see. You may assume that they are top-border of `td` element one below, mistakenly; actually they are not.

Answer (score 0):

In ReactJS you can import you stylesheet as follows: `import "./cssFileName.css"`

and then in your component you can do the following:

```
 <tr className="user" onClick={(e) => {
      e.target.classList.toggle(styles[`toggle-${props.color}`])}}>
      <td className="user-row">
        <div>{props.user}</div>
      </td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I am using CSS modules.